# Unable to access repository when trying to install packages

Tags: r, dplyr, cran, install.packages

I am getting the following error message when trying to install packages since updating to R 4.2.2:

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.csiro.au/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

I have seen this is a reasonably common problem and have tried the common solutions being shared, including trying different CRAN mirrors and unticking the "Use secure download method for HTTP" option. This is a work computer, so I am aware that company firewalls can potentially block repository access. However, I have had IT allow the repository URLs to bypass our firewall and check the firewall logs, which has shown no issues.

Any other solutions for this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try installing from file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1474081/680068

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I have tried this. I am able to install packages from files, the issue I have here is that there are a number of packages I need to install and some have a large number of dependencies, making it infeasible to download each and every package.