# package ‘SPARQL’ is not available for this version of R, how can I install SPARQL in Rstudio version 4.2.1?

Tags: r, sparql

Trying to instal SPARQL in Rstudio and got this error:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘SPARQL’ is not available for package ‘disgenet2r’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/disgenet2r’
Warning messages:
1: package ‘SPARQL’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages 
2: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/43/7hr3j7q17tn0ns1g67l5vbq80000gn/T//Rtmptk5KoF/file2d1b24460f94/disgenet2r_0.99.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: If you search for SPARQL, you'll see that [it was removed from the CRAN repository](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SPARQL/index.html) so it can no longer be installed by default. You can try to download and install it manually from the archive (see the link), but since it hasn't been updated for 10 years, it might not work so well

Comment: I have downloaded the package, how do I install the SPARQL.R file in my library for Rstudio

Comment: A quick google search for "r install package from tar.gz" turns up many answers including this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1474081/8366499